# Jacoco is reporting 0 coverage of Kotlin classes by unit tests, in an Android project

Tags: android, gradle, junit, kotlin, jacoco

I'm using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0.

I'm migrating an Android app from java to kotlin. My app has classes in Java and Kotlin, and tests are in Java.

I run `./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport`.

This runs both unit tests (`src/test`) and instrumentation tests (`src/androidTest`).

The report produced by jacoco in `app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html` doesn't show coverage for Kotlin classes which are indeed covered by unit tests.

The report does show coverage correctly from instrumentation tests.

Note: I came across these other questions, which aren't exactly the same issue:

- [JaCoCo returning 0% Coverage with Kotlin and Android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464138/jacoco-returning-0-coverage-with-kotlin-and-android-3-0) has a problem with code coverage by instrumentation tests, not unit tests.
- [Android Studio JaCoCo reports 0% coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044798/android-studio-jacoco-reports-0-coverage) has a problem with code coverage from inside Android Studio, but not Kotlin-specific.

Relevant portions of my app module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
android {
    defaultConfig {
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/main/kotlin"
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                jvmArgs '-noverify', '-ea'
            }
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    ....
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion '0.7.9'
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ["testDebugUnitTest", "createDebugCoverageReport"]) {
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: "${buildDir}",
            includes: ["tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/ca/rmen/android/poetassistant/**/*.class",
                       "intermediates/classes/debug/ca/rmen/android/poetassistant/**/*.class"],
            excludes: ["**/R.class", "**/R*.class", "**/Manifest.class", "**/Manifest*.class", "**/BuildConfig.class",
                       // ignore databinding generated code:
                       "**/ca/rmen/android/poetassistant/databinding/*.class",
                       ... other excludes ...
                       "**/ca/rmen/android/poetassistant/BR.class",
                       "**/com/android/**/*.class"])
    sourceDirectories = files("${project.projectDir}/src/main/java", "${project.projectDir}/src/main/kotlin")
    executionData = fileTree(
            dir: "${buildDir}",
            includes: [
                    "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                    "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
            ])
}
```

Comment: I too was getting 0% coverage.  For others that found this by searching, see my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826020/624814.  I made a very easy mistake that took a few days to track down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add `includeNoLocationClasses = true` to my gradle file as follows, to make the jacoco report reflect the coverage of Kotlin classes by unit tests:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                jvmArgs '-noverify', '-ea'
                jacoco {
                    includeNoLocationClasses = true
                }
            }
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this solution works for running tests from the command line, but I still get 0% coverage when running with coverage from inside Android Studio.

Comment: you are super hero

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in jacoco.gradle file for getting the kotlin classes

```
            def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
```

Ex.

```
def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
            def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
            def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
            sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
            classDirectories.from = files([debugTree], [kotlinDebugTree])
            executionData.from = fileTree(dir: buildDir, includes: [
                    "jacoco/test${name}UnitTest.exec",
                    'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
            ])
```

After the adding this line execute the jacoco command again and it will give the coverage of unit test cases also.