# Gradle, Kotlin, Junit5 and Jacoco - 0% coverage reported

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jacoco, junit5

We would like to use Gradle in conjunction with Kotlin and Jacoco (+JUnit 5) for generating a code coverage report.

Our project directory tree looks as follows:

`project/{src,test}/main/kotlin ...`

Our build.gradle file looks as follows:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.9"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports")
    applyTo junitPlatformTest
}
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage report."
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/classes/kotlin/main"
    )
    def coverageSourceDirs = [
            "src/main/kotlin"
    ]
    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/junitPlatformTest.exec")
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        csv.enabled = true
    }

}
test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/junitPlatformTest.exec")
        includeNoLocationClasses = true
    }
}
test.dependsOn junitPlatformTest
```

With this configuration, Jacoco generates a html report and puts it under `build/reports/test/html`. However, it shows me 0% coverage. This should not be the case, because I have one test case that excercices all methods for a single dummy class in the project.

I went through several posts such as:

- http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2017/12/20/how-to-configure-jacoco-for-kotlin-and-java-project/
- [Jacoco is reporting 0 coverage of Kotlin classes by unit tests, in an Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499351/jacoco-is-reporting-0-coverage-of-kotlin-classes-by-unit-tests-in-an-android-pr?rq=1)
- [JaCoCo returning 0% Coverage with Kotlin and Android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464138/jacoco-returning-0-coverage-with-kotlin-and-android-3-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

However, I could not quite find a solution that worked for me, yet.

Comment: This is odd... after renaming my JUnit test from TestXY to XYTest it seems to work. I must have missed some constraints regarding the naming convention.

Comment: The `junit-platform-gradle-plugin` uses a standard include pattern unless configured explicitly: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/ClassNameFilter.html#STANDARD_INCLUDE_PATTERN

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc! I have missed that point in the documentation.

Comment: This link helped me: https://kevcodez.de/index.php/2018/08/test-coverage-in-kotlin-with-jacoco/

Comment: The URL that Marcin Stachniuk mentioned is now https://kevcodez.de/posts/2018-08-19-test-coverage-in-kotlin-with-jacoco/

Comment: Worth a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194456/jacoco-code-coverage-0-in-android-kotlin-project/69051614#69051614

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit this issue when upgrading form junit 4 -> 5. In my case I had to re-arrange the declaration of the dependencies as outlined here. If you change to this format you should see the coverage reported correctly again without having to change any other configuration.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```