# Android || Sonar Code Coverage issue with hilt(Dependency Injection)

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco, robolectric, dagger-hilt

I am  getting issue with hilt, code coverage is showing all time 0%,  before hilt code coverage is proper calculate using jacoco. but after after using hilt all test case is working fine but code coverage is not calculate.

I have tried both ----

```
hilt {
    enableTransformForLocalTests = true
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

I have tried above all posible options provide by hilt. But there is not any success on coverage and it's still **0%**

I have tried below all suggestions and some tracker issue on google,but not getting any exact solution.
[1). First Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161300933)
[2). Second Link](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1982)
[3). Third Link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/google/dagger/1982/710121692)
[4). Fourth Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194456/jacoco-code-coverage-0-in-android-kotlin-project)

Please help me to sort out from this problem. Thanks

Comment: Hello @sourav-agrawal, did you find any solution ?