# Unit Test coverage not sync and saved in Android Studio Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

Below Alert prompted after run unit test cases in Android Studio for code coverage.
After Recompile clicked below error comes.

```
Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true
```

Solution Tried :

> Clean Build

> Rebuild

> Invalidate Cache & Restart

> Optimize Imports

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with JaCoCo test coverage, and the same dialog was prompted to me when I tried to run Android Studio coverage.

The issue for the JaCoCo was related to the Android Gradle Plugin issue.
AGP <7.2 had an issue with creating test coverage reports.

Upgrading Android Gradle Plugin solved this issue for me.

For more details related to this, you can check here: [Jacoco code coverage 0% in Android-kotlin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194456/jacoco-code-coverage-0-in-android-kotlin-project/72643244#72643244)